# How can I set python path and version for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Couldn’t load SIP Module](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31036/couldnt-load-sip-module)

When I'm starting QGIS I'm getting the problem:
"Couldn't load SIP module. Python support will be disabled."
And there is also:

```
Python version: 2.6.5
Python path: ['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/usr/lib/python2.6'...]
```

I actually have SIP but my current python version is 2.7 so SIP located at `/usr/lib/python2.7`

So how can I set the right version of Python and Python path for QGIS?

P.S. `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7` doesn't work