# cannot load moule sip qgis 2.8.2

Tags: qgis, sip

i have an error when i launch the qgis 2.8.2 it says that the module sip cannot be load
python 2.7 has been installed

i am under ubuntu 14

please if you have any idea

here is the message (in french sorry ):

Le module SIP n'a pas pu être chargé.
Le support Python va être désactivé.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named sip

Version de Python :
2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 23:03:14) 
[GCC 4.8.2]

Version de QGIS :
2.8.2-Wien 'Wien', exported

Chemin vers Python :
['/usr/share/qgis/python', u'/home/flodev/.qgis2/python', u'/home/flodev/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Comment: Try to install python-sip package or if it exists downgrade it.

Comment: i have just download the python-sip package from riverbankcomputing, it is the version 4.16.8, i install it using python configure.py , then make , then make install and i have the same error when i try to launch qgis

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31036/couldnt-load-sip-module