# QGIS - Python Error on Startup (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: qgis, python

After installing the 3.4.x Madeira LTR release, upon opening QGIS I am encountering the following error:

```
Couldn't load SIP module.
Python support will be disabled.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'


Python version:
3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]

QGIS version:
3.4.10-Madeira 'Madeira', 3d97aaae88

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/wporter/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python', '/home/wporter/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/wporter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

I suspect the issue lies with my Python path (or possibly anaconda?), but I did recently upgrade from Xenial to Bionic so I suspect that may also be a factor.

How can I resolve or begin to troubleshoot this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'`?

`sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
...
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr bionic main
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr bionic main
```

Possibly related:

[QGIS 2.18.3 path and sip module cannot be load in ubuntu 16.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229115/qgis-2-18-3-path-and-sip-module-cannot-be-load-in-ubuntu-16-04)

[Couldn't load SIP Module](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31036/couldnt-load-sip-module)

**Update 7-23-2019**

Digging further, I've noticed the `qgis` directory and `PyQt5` directory seem to be missing from `/usr/share/qgis/python`

`ls -l /usr/share/qgis/python` returns...

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 22 16:16 console
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 22 16:16 plugins
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 22 16:16 pyplugin_installer
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 22 16:16 qsci_apis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda was the problem.  I launched qgis without errors by removing all the anaconda directories from `$PATH`:

```sh
PATH=$(python -c "print(':'.join(i for i in '$PATH'.split(':') if 'anaconda' not in i))")
echo $PATH # verify anaconda removed, but nothing else is
qgis
```

Answer (score 1):

Reimaging my machine addressed the issue.

I was able to install without the error with a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. In case it's helpful to anyone in the future, I suspect a recent installation of Anaconda was the real culprit but I'm still not entirely sure it wasn't the upgrade from Xenial to Bionic.