# No SIP module on Mac OS after installing Boundless Desktop 1.1.0 product

Tags: python, pyqgis, mac, boundless-suite, sip

After installing a Boundless Desktop 1.1.0 product, when I tried to start QGIS, it gave an following error and processing toolbox does not started.

> Couldn't load SIP module. Python support will be disabled.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  ImportError:
>   No module named sip

I tried to install SIP module using the pip in boundless command prompt was unsuccessful. I also taken care as given as [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31036/couldnt-load-sip-module). But that does not work. Please suggest the issues.

Comment: can you send your path variable please ? under qgis open python console and sent the return of `import sys` `sys.path`

Comment: @Hugo Roussaffa

The sys.path is

['', '/Library/Boundless/Desktop/1.1/opt/gdal2-python/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Boundless/Desktop/1.1/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Boundless/Desktop/1.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Boundless/Desktop/1.1/opt/qgis2-bdesk/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python', '/Library/Boundless/Desktop/1.1/opt/qgis2-bdesk/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins', '/Library/Boundless/Desktop/1.1/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',

Comment: when you try to manually `import sip`  you get the error, isn't it ?

Comment: yes, I get an error

Comment: "I tried to install SIP module using the pip in boundless command prompt was unsuccessful." dit you get any error ?

Comment: @osmjit, does `/Library/Boundless/Desktop/1.1/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/sip.so` not exist? Also, which macOS?