# QGIS 3.4.6 Cannot create fields in new shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3, windows-10

Running 3.4.6 on Windows 10.  Until today I have had no problems creating new shapefiles and fields. Now when I create a new shapefile everything in the new dialog box works as usual when I create fields, then when done I click OK to save and open the attribute table the fields are not there and the visible fields are "Actions" and "_1", "_2" etc. depending on the number of fields originally created. I get the same result when I try to add fields. I have tried this with multiple new shapefiles. How do I get the normal behavior for adding new shapefiles and fields? [image: Dialog box before "OK:]

I am getting an SIP module error disabling Python on startup. This is probably the source of the problem but I can't seem to fix that. I have posted question and photo of error messages at [Couldn't load SIP Module](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31036/couldnt-load-sip-module/332090#332090) but if anyone here can help please let me know!

[image: Entry form for field when new feature is created]

[image: Saved feature on map and attribute tabel]]

Comment: Can you add new fields in edit mode in the attribute table? So after creating the shapefile?

Comment: When I add a new field it is not saved.

Comment: I can add or edit polygons in an existing shapefile, but I cannot create new shapefiles. When I try to create a new shapefile I get the error "Layer creation failed: Failure to create file XXX.shp:permission denied."  Version 3.4 was working fine for me until there was  Windows update in July.

Comment: I am able to creates new projects and create/edit shapefiles in QGIS v.2.1, but the problem with 3.4 persists for me.