# Amnesic installation of QGIS 3.4 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, configuration

I installed QGIS 3.4 with the repository https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr bionic main on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine.
I had some troubles due to the presence of several repositories listed in my file sources.list. But now the software is installed and is properly running.

However its settings are not stable : neither the toolbar's display nor the location of the panels
nor the import of my personalized color palette nor even the recently opened project files
nor the connection to the databases are kept by the software.

I checked if the profile folder existed : /home/user/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default.
It's here, no problem. It has even the correct writing accesses for the owner and its group (and is "read-only" for the other users).

Do you have some clues?

Comment: Do you have any self-compiled GIS-related stuff on your machine? Looks similar to the problems in  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313294/cant-install-support-for-ecw-in-qgis-3-6-3-4-on-ubuntu-18-04 or updated python modules as in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31036/couldnt-load-sip-module

Comment: Hello AndreJ. No, I've no self-compiled stuff on this machine. There was a time when I played with it, compiling GDAL and QGIS in order to manage ECW format! ;-) But not on this PC.

Comment: Did you update anything from Python with pip? Do you get error messages in the QGIS log section?

Comment: No, it was just a basic install. And I've got no error in logs. But I finally managed to domesticate my QGIS! I don't know why, the QGIS3.ini file (and only it) was read-only. I changed basic rights on it, and now QGIS remember its configuration! Thank you anyway for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally it was an access rights problem, but not at folder level.
The ini file (/home/user/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/QGIS/QGIS3.ini) was read-only (I really don't know why).
I simply changed its access rights with chmod, and QGIS recovered its memory!